# How can I show the quotient of the $k$th partial sums of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} n^2$ is $\frac{3}{2k+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I've found using pen and paper that any trivial case of the sum of a sequence of integers from $1$ to $k$ divided by the sum of the squares of these integers  is equal to $\frac{3}{2k+1}$

for example,

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1+2+3}{1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}} &= \frac{3}{7}\\
\frac{1+2+3\ +\ 4}{1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}+4^{2}} &= \frac{3}{9}\\
\frac{1+2+3\ +\ 4\ +5}{1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}+4^{2}+5^{2}} &= \frac{3}{11}\\
\frac{1+2+3\ +\ 4\ +5+6}{1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}+4^{2}+5^{2}+6^{2}} &= \frac{3}{13}
\end{split}
$$

Using a computer I can verify this is true for very large values of $k$ and so I intuitively assume it is true for all values of $k$ but how do I prove this?

I've come up with the following equation to represent this as the quotient of two partial sums but don't know how to get from the left side of the equation to the right.

$$\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^k n}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^k n^2} = \frac{3}{2k+1}$$

Comment: Do you know formulas for the partial sums $\sum_{n = 1}^{k} n$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^{k} n^2$?

Comment: No I'm afraid that my knowledge of partial sums is limited.

Comment: A better title that avoids infinite sums that do not exist: "How can I show the quotient of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} n^2$ is $\frac{3}{2k+1}$?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are explicit formulas for the partial sum (that can e.g. be shown by induction):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k n = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k n^2 = \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}.
$$
Take the ratio, and you get your formula.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig took the liberty to correct the type, +1 for the answer

Comment: Ah ok I see that word induction is bringing something back to me now. This is the missing link! I knew that these *partial sums must have been very trivial. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

As we know or we can easily prove, $\sum_{n=1}^kn = \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}$

Now expanding, $(n-1)^3 = n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n - 1$

$n^3 - (n-1)^3 = 3n^2 - 3n + 1$

$ \sum_{n=1}^k n^3 - (n-1)^3 = 3\sum_{n=1}^kn^2 - 3\sum_{n=1}^kn + \sum_{n=1}^k1$

$ k^3 = 3\sum_{n=1}^kn^2 - 3\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2} + k$

$ 3\sum_{n=1}^kn^2 = k^3 + 3\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2} - k$

$ \sum_{n=1}^kn^2 = \dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$